# Nagios plugin displays wrong results

Tags: nagios

I would like to check number of MySQL databases. I've created simple test "plugin":

Location: `/var/lib64/nagios/plugins

test:

```
#!/bin/bash

db=$(mysql -e 'SHOW DATABASES' | wc -l)
echo $db
```

It works from the local machine:

```
# ./test 
71
```

- however when executed from Nagios server it displays "0"

NRPE config:

```
command[test]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/test
```

Nagios server:

```
# ./check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.10 -c "test"
0
```

Reagrds

Comment: Log the output of the `db=$(mysql -e 'SHOW DATABASES' | wc -l)` to a file. Possibly `mysql` is not in $PATH and/or the user as which it runs has no access to MySQL.

Comment: Has the nagios user access to run the mysql command without any passwords etc? Try with su!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPRE commands usually run as `nagios`. It seems like your query is actually polling how many databases your `nagios` user can see.

There are several solutions to your problem:

- Add user and password information to your command (`mysql -uroot -proot -e 'SHOW DATABASES' | wc -l`);
- Add `nagios` to your `sudoers` file, so that he can run mysql as root (`nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/mysql -e 'SHOW DATABASES'`);
- Add a nagios user to your database with sufficient permissions to see all databases ([mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases)) - **RECOMMENDED**;

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you should consult http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/pluginapi.html as the output from the shown in your plug-in script is quite non-standard for Nagios andf will cause problems.